# Property 'auth' does not exist in type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create authentication with auth, but I get this error.
I've searched forums, but possible solutions still do not give me results.
Any idea how to fix it I would really appreciate it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from './user.model'

import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Screenshot
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newest version of Angular fire, you don't need the .auth part.  Also, you should post your code instead of a screenshot

Comment: I couldn't as it was more code than question, I'msorry.
But I remove the .auth from the import or from the code?

Comment: You were right, it was if I didn't remove the .auth from the code. I really appreciate it


async googleSignin() {
    const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
  }